# PyQt: How to integrate a Calendarwidget in a table view?

Tags: user-interface, date, pyqt

I have the following code:

class DateDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    return QtGui.QCalendarWidget(parent)
```

(...)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
```

(...)

```
    self.liste_Produits = QtGui.QTableView()
    self.ProduitsModel = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
    self.liste_Produits.setModel(self.ProduitsModel)
    self.liste_Produits.setItemDelegateForColumn(3,DateDelegate(self))
```

The problem is that the calendar widget remains contained within the cell with the date to be edited.
How can I have the calendar widget show up like a sort of modal dialog, e.g. on top of the table view instead of within the table cell?

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Too easy: 
In the `createEditor` method, return a subclassed `QDateEdit` widget, defined with:

```
class TableCalendarWidget(QtGui.QDateEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(TableCalendarWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCalendarPopup(True)
```

That's it!

Comment: You don't need to subclass for that. Returning a regular `QDateEdit` instance with `.setCalendarPopup(True)` used on it would do.

Comment: @Avaris: Thank you for the feedback.
`createEditor:
        theWidget = QtGui.QDateEdit(parent)
        theWidget.setCalendarPopup(True)
        return theWidget`
Works indeed very well!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a continuation of the comments from Andres:

```
class DateDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        calendar_widget = QDateEdit(parent)
        calendar_widget.setCalendarPopup(True)
        return calendar_widget
```

and in your MainWindow class:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.liste_Produits = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.ProduitsModel = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.liste_Produits.setModel(self.ProduitsModel)
        self.date_delegate = DateDelegate()
        self.liste_Produits.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, self.date_delegate)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).